# Unsupported Operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType' (FFN)

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I am pursuing a Deep Learning Course on GUVI wiz being managed by IIT Chennai known as PadhaiOneFourthLabs. I am currently in the Feed Forward Neural Networks now. This error is persistent and wouldn't go how much ever i try. The code that i implemented is:

```
class SigmoidNeuron():
  def __init__(self):
    self.w = None 
    self.b = None

  def perceptron(self,e):
    return (np.dot(e,self.w) + self.b)

  def sigmoid(self,e):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-e))

  def grad_w_mse(self,e,f):
    f_cal = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(e))
    return (f_cal - f) * f_cal * (1 - f_cal) * e

  def grad_b_mse(self,e,f):
    f_cal = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(e))
    return (f_cal - f) * f_cal * (1 - f_cal)

  def grad_w_ce(self,e,f):
    f_cal = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(e))
    if f == 0:
      return f_cal * e
    elif f == 1:
      return  -1 * (1-f_cal) * e
    else: 
      raise ValueError("f can only be 0 or 1")

  def grad_b_ce(self,e,f):
    if f == 0:
      return f_cal
    elif f == 1:
      return -1 * (1-f_cal)
    else:
      raise ValueError('f can only be 1 or 0')

  def fit(self,E,F,epochs= 1,learning_rate= 1, initialise= True, loss_func= "mse", display_loss = False):
    if initialise:
      self.w  = None
      self.b  = None

    if display_loss:
      loss = {}

    for i in tqdm_notebook(range(epochs), total= epochs, unit = "epoch"):
      dw = 0
      db = 0
      for e,f in zip (E,F):
        if loss_func == "mse":
          dw += self.grad_w_mse(e,f)
          db += self.grad_b_mse(e,f)
        elif loss_func == "ce":
          dw += self.grad_w_ce(e,f)
          db += self.grad_b_ce(e,f)

      m = E.shape[1]
      self.w -= learning_rate * dw/m
      self.b -= learning_rate * db/m

      if display_loss:
        F_cal = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(E))
        if loss_func == "mse":
          loss[i] = mean_squared_error(F,F_cal)
        elif loss_func =="ce":
          loss[i] = log_loss(F,F_cal)
    if display_loss:
      plt.plot(list(loss.values()))
      plt.xlabel('Epochs')
      if loss_func == "mse":
        plt.ylabel('Mean Squared Error')
      elif loss_func == "ce":
        plt.ylabel('Log Loss')
      plt.show()

  def predict(self,E):
    F_cal = []

    for e in E:
      f_cal = self.sigmoid(self.perceptron(e))
      F_cal.append(f_cal)
    return np.array(F_cal)
```

The error i get is displayed as:

> ```
>     TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
>     <ipython-input-30-bd02664ff1b8> in <module>()
>           1 S = SigmoidNeuron()
>     ----> 2 S.fit(E_train,F_train,epochs = 1000, learning_rate = 0.5, display_loss = True)
>
>     2 frames
>     <ipython-input-23-891427be7d2d> in perceptron(self, e)
>           5 
>           6   def perceptron(self,e):
>     ----> 7     return (np.dot(e,self.w) + self.b)
>           8 
>           9   def sigmoid(self,e):
>
>     <__array_function__ internals> in dot(*args, **kwargs)
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'float' and 'NoneType'
> ```

I have tried to change the code as much as i can, but no matter what, the error remains as it is.

Kindly help me out with this so that i may able to proceed further.

THANKS